# 3D pie chart in angular 4 is not taking effect of 3d

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, 3d

I'm using angular 4 and like to display 3d pie chart onto the screen. I'm using highchart library for this. But chart is rendering as 2d.
Please see my code below:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("container") as HTMLElement;
var chart = Highcharts.chart(ctx, {
  chart: {
      type: 'pie',
      options3d: {
          enabled: true,
          alpha: 45,
          beta: 0

      }
  },
  plotOptions: {
      pie: {
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          depth: 35,
          dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              format: '{point.name}'
          }
      }
  },
  title: {
      text: ''
  },
  colors:['#f39c12','#2ecc71','#d35400'],
  tooltip: {
      enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Browser share',
      data: [
          [this.getOpexEnergy.label + ' [' + this.getOpexEnergy.Comparission.toFixed(2) + '% ]', +this.getOpexEnergy.value],
          [this.getOpexMaintenance.label + ' [' + this._MaintenanceOpex.Comparission.toFixed(2) + '% ]', +this.getOpexMaintenance.value],
          [this.getOpexOperation.label + ' [' + this._OperationOpex.Comparission.toFixed(2) + '% ]', +this._OperationOpex.value]
      ]
  }]
});
```

[image: 2d pie chart]

Comment: Did you load necessary highcharts-3d.js script? Without it pie chart indeed displays without 3D effect. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/y59Lqdov/.

Comment: Could you please tell me the steps to add this in angular 4